# Java compiling error on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

So I'm working on this program and I've created two classes, one class called CreditCard, the other called CreditCardTester.I'm using Eclipse IDE and I keep getting compiling errors such as "The method getBalance(double) in the type CreditCard is not applicable for the arguments ()". I'm not really sure on what I have to fix.

This is the first class called CreditCard:

```
public class CreditCard
{
private String accountNumber;
private double creditLimit;
private double balance;

public void CreditCard(String number, double limit)
{
    accountNumber = number;
    limit = creditLimit;
    balance = 0;
}

public String getAccountNumber() 
{
    return accountNumber;
}

public double getCreditLimit() 
{
    return creditLimit;
}

public double getBalance(double theBalance) 
{
    return balance;
}

public double charge(double amount)
{
    balance = balance + amount;

    return balance;
}
```

This is the second class CreditCardTester:

```
public class CreditCardTester
{


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    CreditCard card = CreditCard("1234-5678-9012-3456", 1000.00);

    String formatString = "Credit Card [number = %s, bal = %.2f, limit = %.2f]\n";

    System.out.printf(formatString, card.getAccountNumber(), card.getBalance(), card.getCreditLimit());

    System.out.println("\nCharging $50.00 to credit card...\n");

    card.charge(50.00);

    System.out.printf(formatString, card.getAccountNumber(), card.getBalance(), card.getCreditLimit());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a constructor, because you added `void`, making it a normal method:

```
public void CreditCard(String number, double limit)
```

Remove `void`:

```
public CreditCard(String number, double limit)
```

Also, one of the assignments in the method/constructor is backwards.  You assigned the instance variable to the parameter.

```
limit = creditLimit;
```

Change it around:

```
creditLimit = limit;
```

You're missing "new" when creating a `CreditCard`:

```
CreditCard card = CreditCard("1234-5678-9012-3456", 1000.00);
```

Try

```
CreditCard card = new CreditCard("1234-5678-9012-3456", 1000.00);
```

You have an unused parameter on the `getBalance` method, and you call it without a parameter.

```
public double getBalance(double theBalance)
```

Remove it:

```
public double getBalance()
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! by the way, I was wondering if @rgettman or anyone knew of sources to learn JavaScript. I've tried learning via popular textbooks  or even at my community college but nobody has been able to properly teach me, or maybe i'm the problem who knows, how to code.

Answer (score 0):

I think `getBalance` should not accept an argument in your class definition.

Use this in your `CreditCard` class:

```
public double getBalance() 
{
    return balance;
}
```